# Conditions for writing primary current = m*secondary current transformer

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, electromagnetism

In a transformer, under which conditions can we write the following equation :

[image]

It suppose that the magnetizing inductance is infinite? So the permeability of the core is infinite and the transformer has no gap (so it cannot be applied to a flyback transformer). In other words, it means that the transformer store no energy which can be coupled to the secondary. So the energy is instantaneously transfered to the secondary?

Thank you very much,

Comment: You seem to have asked a question, and given the answer. You've described an ideal transformer. You can use ideal transformer equations whenever that model is suitable for your purposes.

Comment: That was my personnal opinion but I didn't know if it was correct, and any advice is always welcome !

Comment: A better question would be when it is appropriate to use ideal transformer equations, and when should you take into account finite Lm, finite resistance windings, leakage inductance, saturation effects, eddy currents etc etc etc

Comment: You can have a look at an article I published in How2Power.com where I explain how the leakage inductance reduces the secondary-side peak current: http://www.how2power.com/newsletters/1101/articles/H2PToday1101_design_ON%20Semi.pdf?NOREDIR=1 and affects the maximum output power.

Comment: I have already read the first part of your article ! It is really nice ! :D I will take a look afterwards

Comment: Actually I m looking for the formula which give the limit between CCM and DCM for a flyback converter. I have already a formula but it assumes a perfect transformer...